# How to Referencing a xml file in J2EE project to add a node?

Tags: xml, jakarta-ee, path, nodes

I'm trying to add node to xml file , but how to know its path in J2EE project, i use this but it doses not working `Document document = documentBuilder.parse("D:/J2EE/workspace/BanqueXML/users.xml");`

Answer (score 0):

The method with a `String` as an argument (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29) takes a URI, so in case you want to load a document from the file system try `documentBuilder.parse("file:///D:/J2EE/workspace/BanqueXML/users.xml")`. There might be ways in J2EE to map the relative path like `BanqueXML/users.xml` to a file path and a file path to a URI, someone more skilled in that area can hopefully tell you that.